# How can I use a function argument in selecting data from an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys (and gals) just trying to select data from an Object, this is the object returned from the API I'm using:

[image]

and I'm using this function:

```
success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            loadData(data, 'Finalphase', 'f');

        }
    })
})

function loadData(data, usname, initial) {
    $('#' + initial + 'Wins').text(data.list.usname.stats.global.kills);
}
```

But I get an error at usname, which is really Finalphase which looks like it should work just fine. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong and any information would be great, thanks :)

Comment: There is no data.list.usname in your graphic.

Comment: @lucuma I'm accessing the object by using the 'data' argument it is stored in, and usname is the argument I need to figure out how to pass to the line

Comment: The answer is below.  The reason what you wrote doesn't work is because your json data does not have a data.list.usname element.  If you are going to be parsing a lot of json you may want to check to see if it is there first and/or use some of the great js libs out there like lodash or underscore to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to access the list using the key `usname`:

```
data.list[usname].stats.global.kills
```

Comment: Thanks for this, any idea why I'm getting    `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Finalphase' of undefined `

Comment: no it was cause I wasn't using dataType: 'JSON' so it actually wasn't returning an object. Thanks though this helped!